EF Core Database Model creation with IDatabaseModelFactory.Create() slow
I'm using EfCore.SchemaCompare with a MariaDB Database (10.4.12) over Pomelo inside .NET 8.
The Compare is working but very slow.
Inside EfCore.SchemaCompare the Method databaseFactory.Create() (microsoft.com: IDatabaseModelFactory.Create()) is loading > 10 minutes for one Database with around 100 Tables.
The following query takes around 3-5 Seconds and is executed per table.
Removing DELETE_RULE select column from the query speeds the load times up to a query time less than 100ms.
>3000ms:
SELECT
    `CONSTRAINT_NAME`,
    `TABLE_NAME`,
    `REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME`,
    GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS('|', `COLUMN_NAME`, `REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME`) ORDER BY `ORDINAL_POSITION` SEPARATOR ',') AS PAIRED_COLUMNS,
    (SELECT `DELETE_RULE` FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS` WHERE `REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS`.`CONSTRAINT_NAME` = `KEY_COLUMN_USAGE`.`CONSTRAINT_NAME` AND `REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS`.`CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA` = `KEY_COLUMN_USAGE`.`CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA`) AS `DELETE_RULE`
 FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`KEY_COLUMN_USAGE`
 WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA` = '###DATABASE###'
        AND `TABLE_NAME` = '###TABLE###'
        AND `CONSTRAINT_NAME` <> 'PRIMARY'
        AND `REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME` IS NOT NULL
        GROUP BY `CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA`,
        `CONSTRAINT_NAME`,
        `TABLE_NAME`,
        `REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME`

<100ms:
SELECT
    `CONSTRAINT_NAME`,
    `TABLE_NAME`,
    `REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME`,
    GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS('|', `COLUMN_NAME`, `REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME`) ORDER BY `ORDINAL_POSITION` SEPARATOR ',') AS PAIRED_COLUMNS
 FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`KEY_COLUMN_USAGE`
 WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA` = '###DATABASE###'
        AND `TABLE_NAME` = '###TABLE###'
        AND `CONSTRAINT_NAME` <> 'PRIMARY'
        AND `REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME` IS NOT NULL
        GROUP BY `CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA`,
        `CONSTRAINT_NAME`,
        `TABLE_NAME`,
        `REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME`

I currently do not want to compare DeleteBehavior but cannot find a way to remove the unecessary loading (time).
Is there a way to speed this up by running the queries parallel from my code before IDatabaseModelFactory.Create() and/or caching the INFORMATION_SCHEMA table content somehow?
I did not find any similar problems on the github page of EfCore.SchemaCompare because maybe it has to do with pomelo optimization and nobody semingly used this combination.
It should be working as mentioned in this Issues and "quickly" as stated inside the readme.
Update 1:
Upgrading to MariaDB 10.11.7 (current LTS) significantly reduced loading time from >10 minutes to ~45 seconds.
Test with upcoming LTS Version (11.4.1 RC) is again ~45 seconds.
I still think the Method and it's exceuted query is not optimised as it should be.
Because with manuell reading all INFORMATION_SCHEMA informations / using own queries based on Query to return database, schema, table, column for all databases it took less than 5 seconds (no more, if my queries are not incomplete) for around 35k rows as result.
This <5 seconds matches more what i am expecting or am i missing something?

What's the actual problem? Generating the model from the database is a development activity done rarely in a project. ORMs Map application Objects to Relational structures, they aren't models of live databases so reverse engineering a database is not something that needs significant optimization.

Apart from that, the question's query is pretty basic, querying the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE system table.  and depends entirely on the database implementation. The schema tables may not even be actual tables but views over system metadata. How fast does MySQL Workbench Schema Comparison work in the same situation?

Yes, you are right it is mostly used for development activity. There is at least one other use cases and overall i value my and others time. The use case is detailed within the Docs of EfCore.SchemaCompare. TLDR: EF Core does not provide a mechanism (at least i and other couldn't find one) for making sure DB First/SQL First (NOT Code First) EF Core Entities are correct and there is no mismatch with the currently used database. Because if you don't check and have a mismatch EF Core throws Exceptions at runtime but first at the usage of the specific Code/EF Model (unfortunately not at startup)

You're already lost far more time than running the comparison once a month would justify. The TLDR is fundamentally wrong. ORMs aren't models of the live database. Entities aren't tables. Objects are the primary actor. IT DOESN'T MATTER AT ALL what the tables are as long as you can map them to any database, whether it's MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, DB2

Even without ORMs good DBAs use views, functions and stored procedures to isolate applications from the actual database implementation, allowing them to split columns or tables, rename them or combine them, without affecting client applications. Databases aren't implementation details and they rarely serve a single application

Thanks for your Input, i may be wrong. Is the Autor of "EfCore.SchemaCompare" wrong? (the nuget package is heavily used 866k downloads). Can you link me addtional resources or a discussion/thead where i can read into the details you provided?

As for does not provide a mechanism that's Migrations, which is meant only for development or very simple scenarios, precisely because a database serves many applications and many scenarios, not just a single one. Besides, let's say the schema comparison fails, then what? Do you abort the application? Why didn't the app deployment perform the migrations it should have? Database migrations aren't trivial and need a specific strategy. One is to use scripts, recorded in the database itself. Schema comparison requires specific tools and far stricter control. That's the way taken by SSDT

Is the Autor of "EfCore.SchemaCompare" wrong? no, the use is wrong. Why didn't the app deployment take care of the database migration? There are appropriate tools for database migration, which work at the database level because ... it's a database migration. Some things like column or table splits or merged can't be handled with a schema comparison. Those tools do record versions, so they know what the current state is and what to apply. The app can check the version stored by those tools to see if it's compatible

The description of "EfCore.SchemaCompare" states If you are changing the schema of your database's schema outside of EF Core' migrations, say by using SQL change scripts, then this library can quickly tell you if the a specific database schema and EF Core's Model of the database are in step. that is exactly what i am trying to used it for...

More like checking for schema drift, which is not the job of EF at all. It's the job of database tools and schema control. Even Redgate which provides the best schema comparison tools, light years ahead of simple column and type comparisons, doesn't use them for deployments. They offer version control of the schema instead and tools based on both version control and schema comparison, along with drift checks.

As an example, that DELETE_RULE specifies whether deletions cascade automatically. If you remove that check, and your code depends on cascading deletes, you risk runtime errors due to FK violations.

A quick, dirty and fast way to check for drift is to export the list of tables, columns, rules etc to a list (as JSON, XML, whatever), reproduce the same at deployment and compare them.

Your are right. I didn't know that there is this difference (keyword "schema drift"). My original question is answered (the performance is suitable), thank you very much. You seen very expericed how should i answer/close this stackoverflow question or can you post a answer and i accept to make this more visible for other developers like me?
